# How to create simple python project using buildout?

Tags: python, django, buildout

I'm developing a Django application with buildout. I configured everything properly, it's working like a charm (at least during the development).

I want to create a companion project (module?), within the same buildout.cfg. How do you do that with buildout? I want my module to use tornado web server to serve deferred results, independently from django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add another part:

```
[buildout]
parts = django tornado

[django]
recipe = z3c.recipe.scripts
eggs =
    Django
    # DjangoDevKit

[tornado]
recipe = z3c.recipe.scripts
eggs = Tornado
```

Comment: what's the difference between z3c.recipe.scipts and zc.recipe.egg?